# What is the correct or rather most secure way to open and close files in python?

Tags: python, file

I found many articels about this topic, but it didn't become clear to me which is the correct or rather most secure way to open and close files in python. Maybe there are more ways to use files in python, but most often I have come across these two ways:

**Example 1:**

```
with open("example.txt", "r") as f:
   # do things
```

**Example 2:**

```
f = open("example.txt", "r")
try:
   # do things
finally:
   f.close()
```

As far as I know, the only difference is that you can raise exceptions in the try..finally block. Is this correct or are there more differences? And still there is the question, which way is the correct way? I really appreciate any kind of help or suggestion, sheers!

Comment: Did you look into the docu? [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) tells you:  _It is good practice to **use the `with` keyword** when dealing with file objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point. Using `with` is also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks_. Why ask here again?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I saw the documentation. This part came clear to me. But since I can catch exceptions in the try..finally block I wondered if it wouldn't be better to use it. Or is there a way to catch exceptions in with statements?

Comment: From the documentation in my answer:   "If BLOCK raises an exception, the context manager’s __exit__() method is called with three arguments, the exception details (type, value, traceback, the same values returned by sys.exc_info(), which can also be None if no exception occurred). The method’s return value controls whether an exception is re-raised: any false value re-raises the exception, and True will result in suppressing it. You’ll only rarely want to suppress the exception, because if you do the author of the code containing the ‘with’ statement will never realize anything went wrong."

Comment: There is no NEED to catch any exception ***to successfully close the file*** - you can still do your own exception catching inside the with for other purposes - or catch/rethrow them - f.e. if you want to read from the file and convert that to a number but it is a non-number input. The contexthandler ONLY ensures the files is still closed.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I assume by catching an exception, he means he needs to know that the opening of the file failed, and why it failed. Which is a fair enough requirement to have. Silently failing is not usually ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally as from the python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement)

The with-statement is the ideal method to use here, especially as it gives many options (so you can also raise exceptions there, or check if everything went as planned or not)

The with-statement also allows custom call-backs for `__exit__` and `__enter__` with additional parameters to get the current state of the process.

It has some additional methods with context managers that can be more useful.

So in short, if you just use the with statement without any further functions, it basically works to make sure that the resource is closed (here being the data stream), while it also gives you the option to track the closing state, with many more options than a usual try/finally block.

I highly recommend going through the link for more information.

Comment: How does the with statement allow custom callbacks for `__exit__` or `__enter__`, it only does if you implement your own context manager, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does. The answer was general on allowing you to implement more features than a standard try-catch, as well as being the more pythonic way. Within the docs they are described as using context managers, as you said. If my wording was inadequate, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

The most Pythonic way and a [good practice](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) is to open the file using the `with` statement:

```
with open("example.txt", "r") as f:
   # do things
```

And you are correct, the only difference for

```
f = open("example.txt", "r")
try:
   # do things
finally:
   f.close()
```

is that you can have a custom behavior in the finally block.

Note that using `with open("example.txt", "r") as f:` Python internally behaves very similar to your `try-finally` block as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase) states:

> IOBase is also a context manager and therefore supports the with statement. In this example, file is closed after the with statement’s suite is finished—**even if an exception occurs**